# Should tags in Google Tag Manager (GTM) Appear in Network Waterfall?

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager

Recently we moved about 10 tags out of our home page source code and moved them into Google Tag Manager (GTM) to try and speed up our website.  I could have sworn that the tags were not showing up in the network tab of either Firebug or Google Developer Tools in Chrome after we implemented GTM.  This was "good" in the sense that it sped up our home page load time dramatically.

However, recently we noticed that the page is slower and we're getting dinged again by YSlow and Google Page Speed for too many http requests and dns lookups.  Sure enough, the tags are showing up in the network waterfall.  GTM tags are firing properly and there appears to be no errors.  Has this always been the case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With GTM tags are injected into your page via javascript, so they will still show up in the networks tab and still create http requests. GTM might improve the loading speed of your site marginally (since all tags will be loaded asynchronously so loading tags will not block your page) but that is a (for the most part negligible) side effect and not the purpose of tag management.